# Geb page url method from ConfigSlurper

Tags: geb

I am trying to store the urls I need in a config file that gets pulled using ConfigSlurper. I think this may not work but not sure. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please explain why would you need that and how page urls change based on different environments?

Comment: I have multiple sites and each sites have a testing site and then a live site. The sites have a backend and a frontend. So I may have test.abc.com then I would have prod.abc.com.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for functionality provided by [baseUrl](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#the_base_url) configuration. When using `to MyPage` the url which is used by the browser is determined by combining `basUrl` configuration and the `url` property of your page class.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a slightly cleaner method of doing this, you could implement a base page such as the one below - inner class for brevity and to avoid calling protected methods directly - (we have apps on 26 different subdomains!):

```
package page.admin

import geb.Configuration
import geb.Page

class AdminPage extends Page {

    class WrappedConfig extends Configuration {

        WrappedConfig(ConfigObject rawConfig) {
            super(rawConfig)
        }

        String getAdminBaseUrl() {
            return readValue('adminUrl', '<invalid-url>')
        }

    }

    String getPageUrl() {
        WrappedConfig config = new WrappedConfig(browser.config.rawConfig)
        return config.adminBaseUrl + this.class.url
    }

}
```

Your config might look something like this:

```
baseUrl = 'http://base-app.example.net'
adminUrl = 'http://admin-app.example.com'
```

This way, you can still use normal geb syntax:

```
given:
    to PageWhichExtendsAdminPage, 'your-path', key1: 'value1
```

to generate the url `http://admin-app.example.com/your-path/?key1=value1`

Answer (score 0):

I run geb on different locales so I encountered the same issue. I usually load the different urls out of a config file with locale.getCountry() as parameter for the environment.

In the running class I replace the baseUrl with the loaded entry with the ConfigSlurper. The advantage is that I can handle multiple locales and localhost environments. Testing locally vs testing the staging environment.

I have one main spock file containing the whole regression testing and a inheriting spock class for every country. The inheriting spock files doesn't contain much except the country/language encoding in the class name.

The config file:

```
environment{
  CA{
    url="ca.somewhere.com"
    validZipCode=...
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The main class:

```
class MainRegression extends GebReportingSpec{

@Shared Locale locale

def setupSpec(){
  ...
  locale = ParameterReader.getLocale(this.class.name)
  ...
}

def "testing the website"(){
  when: "entering the main url"
  go URLService.getBaseUrl(locale)
  ...

}
```

The inheriting class:

```
@Stepwise
class CaEnRegressionSpec{} // Canada with english language
```

A good way to handle the at-verification with different languages / locales: 
http://ldaley.com/post/1013531080/painless-page-identification-with-geb-grails